# JavaScript substring from string with variable contents

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a string that can contain various bits of information, I need to substring a GUID from this when I cant be certain of the position of the GUID within the string.

Possible versions of the string

> stringVar=email:name@company.com&**room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6**;
>
> stringVar=email:name@company.com&**room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6**&host=HOSTNAME;
>
> stringVar=email:name@company.com&location=SomeCity&**room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6**;

There are a few other permutations of the string with more or less fields, it will always at least contain the GUID.

A rough version of what I have:

```
var room = str.substring(str.lastIndex(room),str.lastIndex(;))
if room.length !== 36
    var room = str.substring(str.lastIndex(room),str.lastIndexOf(&)
```

There must be a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I'd rather use a regex if input string sometimes change

Comment: Another way to use regex `stringVar.match(/room:([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/)[1]`

Comment: Why does some key value pair has `=` and some has `:`. Is it intentional?

Comment: @Rajesh its actually a cookie variable of a proprietary system, so I'm stuck with it unfortunately.

Comment: @haddow64 I have tried to add a generic function to parse your format. Not perfect, but should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There must be a cleaner way to do this?

There is - REGEX.

```
var guid = str.match(/room:([^&]+)/);
```

The match, if found, will then live in `guid[0]`, with the guid alone (minus "room:") in `guid[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use string manipulation, for example:

```js
var stringVar1 = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";
var stringVar2 = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6&host=HOSTNAME";
var stringVar3 = "email:name@company.com&location=SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";

function getRoomId(input) {
  return input
    .split("&") //separate into chunks 
    .find(part => part.startsWith("room:")) //see which starts with room
    .split(":")[1]; //split and return the second part, which is the GUID
}
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar1));
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar2));
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar3));
```

Alternatively a more "dumb" way is to just cut around the string you want. The main disadvantage is that it doesn't look as "fancy" but on the other hand, it will work in all browsers.

```js
var stringVar1 = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";
var stringVar2 = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6&host=HOSTNAME";
var stringVar3 = "email:name@company.com&location=SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";

function getRoomId(input) {
  return input
    .split("room:")[1] //find the part of the string that starts with "room:" and cut there
    .split("&", 1)[0]; //cut again at the next "&" and return the first part
}
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar1));
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar2));
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar3));
```

Finally, you can do an even simpler lookup of indeces which will also work in all browsers:

```js
var stringVar1 = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";
var stringVar2 = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6&host=HOSTNAME";
var stringVar3 = "email:name@company.com&location=SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";

function getRoomId(input) {
  var start = input.indexOf("room:") + 5; //the index is the beginning of "room:", so add 5 characters to get rid of it
  var end = input.indexOf("&", start); //the next "&" after "room:" will be after the GUID
  end = end !== -1? end : input.length; //if there is no next "&", then grab everything until the end of the string
  
  return input.slice(start, end);
}
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar1));
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar2));
console.log(getRoomId(stringVar3));
```

There are other variations but the idea is that it's simple enough to solve by treating it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
/(room:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
```

that would match the following data:

```
room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6  
room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6  
room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6
```

Here is the matching: [demo](http://regexr.com/3eg2r)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a good option but it makes the code difficult to read.

```js
var stringValue = "stringVar=email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6&host=HOSTNAME;"

var pattern = /[\da-zA-Z]{8}-([\da-zA-Z]{4}-){3}[\da-zA-Z]{12}/;

var found = stringValue.match(pattern)

console.log(found[0]);
```

This code snippet is taking a string value and doing a simple [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) using a Regex expression, this returns a result array I am simply taking the first index value out of the resulting array.

http://regexr.com/3amuu

Answer (score 1):

Your 'room' guid only contains hex chars. Use a simple *matching* regex to capture what you need:

```
/&room:([a-f\d-]+)/i
```

and if `room` may appear as the first field in the string (at its beginning), you can enhance it to match at the start of the string as well:

```
/(?:^|&)room:([a-f\d-]+)/i
  ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eVGS0H/1)

**Details**:

- `&room:` - matches the literal char sequence `&room:` (the `(?:^|&)` is an alternation group to match either the start string position (`^`) or (`|`) the `&` symbol)
- `([a-f\d-]+)` - matches and *captures* into Group 1 one or more characters that are ASCII letters in the `a-f` and `A-F` ranges (as the `/i` is a case insensitive mode modifier), digits (`\d`) or `-`.

```js
var strngs = ['stringVar=email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6;', 'stringVar=email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6&host=HOSTNAME;', 'stringVar=email:name@company.com&location=SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6;'];
var re = /&room:([a-f\d-]+)/i;
for (var s of strngs) {
  var res = (m=s.match(re)) ? m[1] : "";
  console.log(s + "\n=>\n" + res); // demo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6;";
var room = str.split("room:")[str.split("room:").length-1].split("&")[0].split(";")[0];
//b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6
```

Comment: You can use `.pop` instead of `[str.split("room:").length-1]`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to create a function that would return you an object.

**Note:** I have changed the format slightly. I have added a `city:SomeCity` in third format.

Basic format is, you can have `=` which will have either a string value or an object but not both. So, `&host=HOSTNAME` is fine, but `location=SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6` is not and I have changed it to `location=city:SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6;`

Point is value after `=` should either contain `:` for every pair or not have it.

#### Sample

```js
function getObjectFromCookieStr(str){
 var r = {};
  str.split("=").reduce(function(p,c){
   var k = ''
   var o = c.split('&').reduce(function(p,c){
     if(c.indexOf(':') > -1){
       var kv = c.split(':');
        p[kv[0]] = kv[1]
      }
      else{
       k=c;
      }
      return p;
    }, {});
    r[p] = Object.keys(o).length >0 ? o : c
    return k;
  });
  return r;
}

var s1 = "stringVar=email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6"
var s2 = "stringVar=email:name@company.com&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6&host=HOSTNAME";
var s3 = "stringVar=email:name@company.com&location=city:SomeCity&room:b83edd0d-fec5-4ec0-8055-60bc0d8eb4b6";

console.log(getObjectFromCookieStr(s1))
console.log(getObjectFromCookieStr(s2))
console.log(getObjectFromCookieStr(s3))
```

Now that we have an object, you just have to loop over object to get value. You can use following function to search in object.

```js
function searchKeyInObj(obj, searckKey) {
  if (JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf(searckKey) < 0) return;
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
      var v = searchKeyInObj(obj[k], searckKey);
      if (v) return v
    } else if (k === searckKey) {
      return obj[k];
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it on following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/yks3gb0u/)